# Confusion about the definition of convergence in metric spaces in Conway's book *A Course in Point-set Topology*

Tags: general-topology, limits, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I have been reading the metric-space part of John B. Conway's *A Course in Point-set Topology*, and the definition of convergence in **metric spaces** seems ambiguous to me.

[image]

The author does not make it clear whether the point $x = \lim_n x_n$ in this definition should fall in $X$ or not. And it seems to me that given some context $x$ could be out of the given metric space, like in this one (**Proposition 1.2.7**), $x$ need not be in $A$:

[image]

But in other part of the book, I find it better to admit that the limit is in the given metric space, e.g. in the following definition of complete metric space:

[image]

That is because, if in **Definition 1.2.10** the limit of Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ is allowed to be outside the space $X$, then I feel (but not quite sure) the following proposition does not make sense, since I  guess to establish the necessity one has to use the hypothesis that the limit of any Cauchy sequence falls in $Y$:

[image]

The question may sound naive, but I really get confused about the seeming inconsistence of the text. Can anyone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance!

**edit:** If there is only one space in the context, things are clear. But in the two propositions I refer to, there is a underlying space X and its subspaces, respectively denoted as A and Y, and the sequences in both cases are in the subspace. It seems in the former case, the text means 'the limit need not be in the subspace A'; but in the latter the text means 'the limit must lie in the subspace Y'. That's what confused me.

Comment: When  you are discussing convergence in a  metric space $X$ your **universal set** is $X$ and there is nothing beyond that in your mind.

Comment: @geetha290krm But in the two propositions I refer to, there is a discussion about convergence in a subspace, and that is exactly what I am confused about. It seems there is an ambiguity about whether the limit is in the subspace or not.

Comment: In both of those propositions, the universal set is $X$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am quite a rookie to set theory, and I am not sure whether I really understand you. So in **Proposition 1.2.14** the meaning of completeness allows the limit $x$ of some Cauchy sequence $\{x_n: x_n \in Y\}$ to fall out of $Y$, is it?

Comment: No, since $Y$ is closed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But if we recognize X as the universal set as you say in your last comment, then the completeness of Y can only ensures that the limit of a Cauchy sequence lies in X, then we cannot establish the closeness of Y based on the completeness of Y. Could you please help me find out which part I misunderstand?

Comment: A subset $Y$ of $X$ is closed if and only if the limit of any convergent sequence of elements of $Y$ belongs to $Y$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137475/discussion-between-zyy-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Comment: If $x$ is not in $X$, what does $d(x,x_n)$ even mean? This is a case where the statement makes it clear that $x$ is thought to be in $X$. The same applies to all the other things.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan If there is only one space in the context, things are clear. But in the two propositions I refer to, there is a underlying space $X$ and its subspaces, respectively denoted as $A$ and $Y$, and the sequences in both cases are in the subspace. It seems in the former proposition, the text means 'the limit need not be in the subspace $A$'; but in the latter the text means 'the limit must lie in the subspace $Y$'. That's what confused me.

Comment: @zyy In the first proposition, $A$ is just a subset of $X$ and not treated as a subspace. And in the second one, writing $(Y,d)$ is technically an abuse of notation (but a very common one) since $d$ should be restricted to $Y\times Y$.

Comment: @zyy So in the second proposition, every Cauchy sequence in $Y$ coverges in $Y$. I agree that the definitions are not written properly and can be confusing. Using terms such as "converges inside a space $Y$" are actually very common to avoid such confusions and I don't know why the author doesn't use it.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Thank you for your clarifying. This question actually has arisen to me for a long time, and after I came into more and more such ambiguities in this book about the term "convergence" I felt that I have to ask about this.